# What is the best way to populate a JTable using MYSQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I read about 2 ways actually :

1. looping through the resultset
   and use a table model . (This is
   slower ?)
2. netbeans uses other
       techniques(which seems a bit
       advanced to me) to return the result
       in a form of a list and binds the
       table with the list . (This doesn't
       create a class which deals with the
       database and I can reuse for many
       tables ?)

So , are there other ways or APIS that are easier or more efficient or both ? and If not which of those methods is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents worth can be found with the example in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) entry.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to extend the AbstractTableModel and use this class to create the JTable.
This is fairly easy to do in Netbeans. Go to your JTable properties and select model. Choose  and click the ellipsis. You add `new MyTableModel(rs)`, between the `jTable1.setModel(` and `);`. If you want you can pass your JDBC ResultSet rs.

Answer (score 0):

Really solution 1 and 2 are basically the same.

I would suggest trying to keep the database and GUI as separate as possible.  Go with something more on the side of option 2.  Loop through the result set and return a list of objects that represent the table.  Then on your GUI side, have a class that takes this List and extends `DefaultTableModel`.